# How to launch multiple applications from mix.exs?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-mix

I have an Elixir app with two applications inside the lib/ folder:

`myproject/lib/app1
myproject/lib/app2`

They both have files which use Application:

`myproject/lib/app1.exs
myproject/lib/app2.exs`

They each implement `start` and spawn a supervision tree.

In `myproject/mix.exs` I tried:

```
  def application do
    [
      mod: {app1, []},
           {app2, []},
      applications: [:foo, :bar]
    ]
  end
```

But all I get are syntax errors on the line with `{app2, []}`.

Is such a thing even possible? If not, what is the right way to launch separate applications with supervision trees in Elixir?

Comment: can you try `mix do  run app1.exs, run app2.exs`

Answer (score 2):

You should add app2 as dependency of app1 and call it in applications, like:

mix.exs for app2:

```
  #...
  def application do
    [
      mod: {My.App2, []},
      applications: [:logger]
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      ...
    ]
  end
  #...
end
```

mix.exs for app1:

```
  def application do
    [
      mod: {My.App1, []},
      applications: [:logger, :my_app2]
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:my_app2, in_umbrella: true}
    ]
  end
  # ...
end
```

This is the case if both apps are in the same umbrella. If not, just add my_app2 as you would (from hex, path or git).

For more information on dependencies and umbrella projects, take a look @ http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/dependencies-and-umbrella-apps.html

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense for app1 to be responsible for starting app2 then another option is to use `Application.start(app2)` inside `app1` where appropriate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).